How to include a code generated Matlab function into a ROS 2 C++ node
I generated a matlab function for a Quadrotor trajectory generation. Now I want to include this function into a pre existing ROS2 C++ node.
Unfortunately, when compiling I get an error:
--- stderr: trajectory_generation
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/trajectory_generation_node.dir/src/trajectory_generation_node.cpp.o: in function `TrajectoryGenerationNode::time_callback_(std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float64MultiArray_<std::allocator<void> > >)':
/home/riccardo/phd/research/nmpc_ws/src/trajectory_generation/src/trajectory_generation_node.cpp:42: undefined reference to `QuadrotorRefTraj(double, double*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/trajectory_generation_node.dir/build.make:167: trajectory_generation_node] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:139: CMakeFiles/trajectory_generation_node.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2

I believe this to be an error related CMakeList file but I can't seem to solve the error.
I included the code generated C++ code into an include folder and into the CMakeList.txt file. Like so:
include_directories(include/trajectory_generation/QuadrotorRefTraj)
include_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023b/extern/include)

I am aware of the possibility of code generating the matlab function already inside a ROS 2 node using the Matlab ROS Toolbox but I was hoping of including the C++ code in order to improve the readability of the ROS 2 node itself and code reutilization.
Also if it helps:
ROS 2 version: Humble
Matlab version: 2023b
Ubuntu version: 22.04 LTS

Thank you in advance.

I managed to solve it. Just as a follow-up, this is the way I did it:
add_library(trajectory_generation_lib
  include/trajectory_generation/QuadrotorRefTraj/QuadrotorRefTraj.cpp
  include/trajectory_generation/QuadrotorRefTraj/rt_nonfinite.cpp
  include/trajectory_generation/QuadrotorRefTraj/rtGetInf.cpp
  include/trajectory_generation/QuadrotorRefTraj/rtGetNaN.cpp
)

And then adding the library to the node add_executable using the target_link_library:
add_executable(trajectory_generation_node
  src/trajectory_generation_node.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(trajectory_generation_node
  trajectory_generation_lib
)

By adding the trajectory_generation_lib library in this way, the linker can find the QuadrotorRefTraj function, resolving the undefined reference error.
If this question receives more attention and also an answer from more expert users I will look into it, otherwise I will select this as the question answer.
Thank you.

Try following

Create a GLOB for your .hh and .cc files.
file(GLOB UniqueName "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hh")

Add the GLOB to executable
add_executable(ExecutableName ${UniqueName} )



Thanks for the input @suresh. I managed to make it work in another way and I posted my solution. But anyway thank you very much.

When including code generated by Matlab it is important you find the dependencies from your matlab root folder. I am not sure if you can use colcon build and simply make the chnges to your CMakeLists.txt as you have shown but when using make (creating a Makefile) you need to flag all the relevant directories.

Hi,
The piece of code I shared in the end works, as the ROS 2 node manages to use the matlab code generated function. I definitely think that may not be the cleanest solutions since I have reached it after a trial and error procedure.
But anyway thanks
